# How to run a χ2 test or Fisher's exact test between independent var (treatment A vs. B) and dependent var (diarrhea, graded from 0 to 5)

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I run the sentence:
tabulate diarrhea treatment, chi2 column exact expected

But what I'd like to obtain is the following:

```
?% grade 0 for treatment A vs. ?% grade 0 for treatment B --and p value
?% grade 1 for treatment A vs. ?% grade 1 for treatment B --and p value
?% grade 2 for treatment A vs. ?% grade 2 for treatment B --and p value
```

etc

This is possible? Thanks...